# Becoming unmarried after Hearthfire was removed?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

So. I had a saved game with Hearthfire. I had two kids and a husband. I uninstalled Hearthfire, and then got on to do something and it saved after I had it uninstalled. I reinstalled Hearthfire and now my husband isn't my husband anymore? When I talk to him it doesn't open up the spouse dialog. Also when I go talk to the priest at the temple of Mara he doesn't say anything about marriage?

Update: My spouse was killed by a dragon. Does this mean I am able to get married again?

Comment: It seems that on console you are unable to re-marry after your partner has died. See [this](http://ign.com/wikis/the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim/Marriage_Partners) post on IGN and from what i have seen, subsequent patches have not fixed this either.

Comment: Generally speaking, uninstalling DLC's and/or mods (on the PC) without starting a new character isn't ideal. The save games are dependent on the plugins that were used when creating them, and removing dependencies can cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Arqade! I deleted the Xbox 360 tag from your question since it isn't really about the Xbox 360 and added skyrim-hearthfire since it has to do with the DLC. I also deleted The-elder-scrolls tag since it only has to do with lore.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you might have married someone while the DLC is activated. Try to remarry since you deleted the DLC by talking to the priest again if you seen the dialogue option about the Temple of Mara. Otherwise, if you have the Amulet of Mara, wear it, and then talk to your "ex". Cheats might work too.